# Python replace() string with color?

Tags: python, syntax-highlighting, colorama

I'm making a Python Syntax Highlighter and basically what it does is replaces keywords in the entered string with colored versions of the same string. Here's a sample of my code (the whole program is basically just copy+pasting this code)

```py
from colorama import Fore
def highlight(text):
  text = text.replace("print", "{}print{}".format(Fore.BLUE, Fore.RESET))
print(text)
```

But when I try to use the following code:

```py
highlight("print hello world")
```

(NOTE: I didn't put brackets because this was simply a test) It just printed `print hello world` in the default color. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to return the value from the function. All you function currently does is replace the local variable with the new text.

Comment: Strings are immutable. The text object that you put into the function argument is not actually modified. That is why you need to return the newly created text object from inside your `highlight` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return updated text. Strnigs are not changeable in python, so if you change some string it will not be change internally, it will be a new string.

```
from colorama import Fore

def highlight(text):
    return text.replace("print", "{}print{}".format(Fore.BLUE, Fore.RESET))

text = highlight("print hello world")
print(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always use CLINT.

```
from clint.textui import puts, colored
puts(colored.red('Text in Red')) 
#Text in Red
```

Much easier to use..

https://clint-notes.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto.html